# MYSQL Search Query when inputs are between range of 0 and 0

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I am developing a Flask web application with Python and mysql where one page has a table with data from the MySQL Database. There is a form on the page with search parameters. Some parameters have the option to insert a numerical range (max and minimum). However when I make both the maximum and minimum 0 it returns every single query.

Below is the code from the routing file

```
if(Value_Min and Value_Max):
    if(sql):
        sql = sql + ' AND Value BETWEEN %s AND %s'
    else:
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM database t1 inner join database_table2 t2 on t1.Factor = t2.Factor WHERE t1.Value BETWEEN %s AND %s'
    vars.append(Value_Min)
    vars.append(Value_Max)
```

How can I fix this? It seems to work fine for other values so I am not sure what makes 0 any different.
Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: What do you think `if(0 and 0)` would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"if(Value_Min and Value_Max):" is evaluating to "if(0 and 0)", which is not going to execute the if block. So your SQL "AND Value BETWEEN %s AND %s" is not being added to your sql query at all.

Maybe a better way of doing this is

```
if (Value_Min is not None) and (Value_Max is not None) :
    if(sql):
        sql = sql + ' AND Value BETWEEN %s AND %s'
    else:
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM database t1 inner join database_table2 t2 on t1.Factor = t2.Factor WHERE t1.Value BETWEEN %s AND %s'
    vars.append(Value_Min)
    vars.append(Value_Max)
```